# 5 figures in a particular way

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

I need to arrange 5 figures in this way:

[image]

I tried it with `\subfigure`, `\begin{subfigure}` and a table inside a table with `\begin{tabular}` but i can't get it to look the way i need it.

It is important that each graphic has it's own caption.

Comment: Please show us the code you tried so far! Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please also indicate how the individual images should be captioned: as Figure 1, Figure 2, ... , Figure 5 or, altneratively, a, b, ... e with an overall caption given separately.

Answer (score 11):

Like this?

[image]

By help of `tabularx` table environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cXX}
\multirow{2}{0.4\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}
\caption{a}
            }
    &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-a} 
        \caption{b} 
        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-b}
            \caption{c}                                      \\
    &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-a}
        \caption{d}
        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-b}
            \caption{e}                                      
\end{tabularx}   
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Now I guess that you probably like to have aligned top and bottom of images. This can be achieved simple by estimating image heights and use of package `adjustbox` or by more sophisticated metzhod with measuring heights of right figures (fig. c + caption of c + fig. e) with help of `savebox`:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
%\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{showframe}% only for showing page layout
\newsavebox{\twofigures}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\savebox{\twofigures}{\begin{tabularx}{0.3\textwidth-\tabcolsep}{X}
                        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}
                        \caption{c}         \\
                        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}
                      \end{tabularx}}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cXX}
\multirow{2}{0.4\textwidth}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,%
                     height=\ht\twofigures+\dp\twofigures,%
                     valign=T]  {example-image}
    \caption{a}

            }
    &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=T]{example-image-a} 
        \caption{b} 
        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=T]{example-image-b}
            \caption{c}                                      \\
    &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=T]{example-image-a}
        \caption{d}
        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=T]{example-image-b}
            \caption{e}                                      
\end{tabularx}   
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum 2:**
In a case, that for images one like to exploit whole text width, with adding `@{}` on begin and end of column specification: `{@{}cXX@{}}`, than you need to change stored images accordingly: without subtracting table width for `\tabcolsep`:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{showframe}
\newsavebox{\twofigures}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\savebox{\twofigures}{\begin{tabularx}{0.3\textwidth}{X}% <-- changed
                        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}
                        \caption{c}         \\
                        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}
                      \end{tabularx}}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}cXX@{}}% <-- changed
\multirow{2}{0.4\textwidth}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,%
                     height=\ht\twofigures+\dp\twofigures,%
                     valign=T]  {example-image}
\caption{a}
            }
    &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=T]{example-image-a} 
        \caption{b} 
        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=T]{example-image-b}
            \caption{c}                                      \\
    &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=T]{example-image-a}
        \caption{d}
        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=T]{example-image-b}
            \caption{e}                                      
\end{tabularx} 
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Added `showframe` package serve only to show page layout. With its visible is easy to comparison difference between second and third solution. In real application it had to be removed.

Comment: Found this old post and works wonderfully; however, the code in **Addendum 2** causes `overfull \hbox` warning when used with `tabularx`. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: sorry it's actually a `\vbox` problem

Comment: @Matteo, this my answer is quite old ... Overfull warnings usually means that image is t(a bit) to wide. This  is no harmful. Temporary I'm very occupied with some work which dead line is next Tuesday noon. If meanwhile I will have some spar time, I will investigate how remedy this warning

Comment: Actually, as my case could/might have been a bit different I also opened another issue. Thankfully, someone answered; I add the link so that you can verify the issue pertinent my case: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/714325/issues-with-overfull-vbox-and-tabularx-figure-arrangement/714328#714328. Thanks anyway!