# issues with overfull \vbox and tabularx figure arrangement

Tags: graphics, positioning, tabularx, multirow, overfull

Hi there I was looking into a clever way to present five figures in `LaTex`. I found this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326400/5-figures-in-a-particular-way) which I believe it's quite useful in my case since I can present an enlarged version for one of the distributions and use it to generalized the feature for the others that, albeit different, use the same information code. *See* below for an example:

[image]

and code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}

\newsavebox{\twofigures}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\savebox{\twofigures}{\begin{tabularx}{0.3\textwidth}{X}
                        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}
                        \caption*{}         \\
                        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}
                      \end{tabularx}}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}cXX@{}}
\multirow{2}{0.4\textwidth}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,%
                     height=\ht\twofigures+\dp\twofigures,%
                     valign=T]{example-image}
                     \caption*{HG002}}
                     
    &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=T]{example-image} 
        \caption*{HG00514} 
        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=T]{example-image}
            \caption*{HG00733}                                      \\
    &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=T]{example-image}
        \caption*{HG03942}
        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=T]{example-image}
            \caption*{NA19240}                                      
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Enter Caption} \label{figure:merqury}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, for some reason the second `tabularx` causes me an *overfull \vbox* warning which I cannot figure out how to suppress... any help would be great, thanks in advance!

P.S. any alternative with similar style and showcasing the same content is well accepted and welcome, too!

Comment: tabularx is doing nothing useful here as you know the widths in advance, but you have not said what the warning is nor provided code that we can run so it is hard to help. please replace the images with example-image or use `\rule{2cm}{3cm}`  or whatever is the right size to show your problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry I didn't know the function of `example-image`. I edited the MWE accordingly. Let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, `tabularx` is doing no good as you already know how wide your pictures should be. The overfull is due, I believe, to `\multirow`, but you're misusing also this tool (which is rarely useful, in my experience).

You want to measure the block of four figures instead and you don't need `\caption*`, that only complicates things. Why? Because you want to scale the picture to match the size of that part, not conversely.

The height of the scaled picture is computed as the height of the block minus `\normalbaselineskip`, to take into account the labels in the bottom line.

A couple of bottom aligned `tabular` constructions do the job; a temporary length is used to avoid repeating the computations over and over again. I subtract four times `\tabcolsep` from `\textwidth`, so the spacings between the columns will be the same.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\newlength{\figuretemp}
\newsavebox{\twofigures}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

% first we set \figuretemp to \textwidth minus 4 times \tabcolsep
\setlength{\figuretemp}{\dimeval{\textwidth-4\tabcolsep}}

\sbox{\twofigures}{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}cc@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\figuretemp]{example-image} & % top left
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\figuretemp]{example-image} \\ % top right
  HG00514 & HG00733 \\[2ex]
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\figuretemp]{example-image} & % bottom left
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\figuretemp]{example-image} \\ % bottom right
  HG03942 & NA19240
  \end{tabular}}

\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
\includegraphics[
  width=0.4\figuretemp,
  height=\dimeval{\ht\twofigures-\normalbaselineskip}
]{example-image} \\
HG002
\end{tabular}\hfill % <--- will insert 2\tabcolsep
\usebox{\twofigures}

\caption{Enter Caption} \label{figure:merqury}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: much appreciated! Also, thanks for the in-depth explanation; I'm quite new to `LaTex` still and I mostly try to understand what the code does and apply it with small changes to my uses/cases. However, unless not in simple scenarios I'm not able to effectively debug issues I'm not familiar with. Thanks a lot, again!